# Is there anyway to save Google colab environment to somewhere and reuse it?

Tags: python, virtualenv, google-colaboratory

I've tried virtualenv and conda, it was successfully installed but I cannot active the virtual environment. Then I think about saving Colab environment (I mean installed libraries) to somewhere, maybe Google Drive then I can reuse it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Every collab session in fact is a virtual environment, i think. I guess what you are looking for is installing all dependecies. May be using a requirements.txt file and installing these with `!pip install -r requirements.txt` magic in the first cell of your notebook is an appropriate solution for you?

Answer (score 4):

For the questioner and for whom reached here because of the same issue,

A good answer was posted after this question :
[How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)

It uses the way you install libraries into your Google Drive.

Comment: The answer there explains how to install individual packages and save them to a local variable, but that doesn't really explain how to do that when you need to install using a requirements.txt file'

Answer (score 1):

You can add a directory in GDrive to PYTHONPATH, e.g. `/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/`

Then Python will search for an installed library there. You still need to mount to GDrive every time, though.

Comment: I mean libraries I installed by pip

Comment: I think you can install by pip. Then manually copy or move the installed directory from inside `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/` to Gdrive. I have never tried it though.

Answer (score -1):

It should be covered in the documentation for virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Once you have created a virtual environment with:

```
virtualenv NAME
```

That creates a new directiory named NAME for your virtual environment.

Then you can activate it with:

```
source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
```

or

```
. /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
```

(note above, "[DOT][SPACE]/path/to/ENV/bin/activate")

That directory should be fine to move around as you please, thumb drive, dropbox, etc. If the systems you intend to use your enviroment on differ too much there could maybe be some issues.

---

However, I prefer to use **pyenv** + **pipenv** for all my virtual environment needs. 
If you have the time I strongly recommend learning about them, it is worth it.

**Pipenv** https://github.com/pypa/pipenv is a great manager for python virtual environments.

**Pyenv** https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv is for installing and managing different versions of python so you might not need it.

This way your virtual environment is more robost and easier to get up and running if you move it around or share it with others.

Comment: It doesn't work on Google colab, I've tried it several times :(