# How to make virtual environment on google colab that can be saved on drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, virtualenv, google-colaboratory, python-venv, miniconda

please, how can i build a virtual environment where the libraries will be preserved and reused on google colab/drive without having to reinstall them again each time?

I tried to clone repos from github and put it in drive but this can't be done for other dependencies like open cv, pandas, numpy ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360838/is-there-anyway-to-save-google-colab-environment-to-somewhere-and-reuse-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anyway to save Google colab environment to somewhere and reuse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360838/is-there-anyway-to-save-google-colab-environment-to-somewhere-and-reuse-it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Vg005uKhgt-ZwyQ11-BGceqY0q07qIzF

While creating the virtual environment (venv), copy paste the path to the folder in your drive where you want to create the venv. Hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).